# How can i deal with websocket multi callback?

Tags: javascript, spring-websocket

- Config - 
  Client: javascript 
  Server(Websocket): Spring Websocket

My problem is I don't know good way how i set multi callback of websocket.onmessage(Client).

```
send:function (message) {
    this.RaphaServerHandler.onmessage = function (evt) {
        callback(evt);
    };

    this.RaphaServerHandler.send(message);

    this.RaphaServerHandler.onerror = function () {
        console.log('WebSocket Error!');
    }
},
```

I try above example. example callback is hash. so I can get callback by key. but I can't send key at websocket(server-side). because sendMessage type is binaryMessage(this is image pixel data).
Anyway My Questions

1. websocket.onmessage(evt) -> evt have a various key: bubbles, data, type, lastEventId etc. i can send just evt.data. Can I(websocket server) set another  thing(header???) if this can! I want to divide callback by header data
2. if first question can't. What is the best way of multi callbacks of websocket?? please help!

Comment: Stomp over websocket supports headers.

Comment: oh... thank you bro..!